# How to get Libertine Initials to work with lettrine?

Tags: fonts, libertine, lettrine, drop-cap

I don't succeed with Libertine Initials and can't find any post on this.

I would like to get Libertine Initials to work with the package `lettrine`. However, I don't get the desired result using this MWE:

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\defaultfontfeatures{%
    ,Ligatures={TeX}
    ,Scale=MatchLowercase
}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O} 
%\setsansfont[Mapping=tex−text]{Linux Biolinum O}%
\newfontfamily\lettrinefont{Linux Libertine Initials O}
%\newfontfamily\lettrinefont{LinLibertineIO}
%\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\fontfamily{\lettrinefont}}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\lettrine[lines=3, slope=-0.5em, nindent=0pt, lhang=0.35]{V}{ariablen} 
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I put in all three possible solutions, I found until now. None is working.

It would be great to get some information about the use of this feature. Are there already some kerning properties set to this font? Or do I have to do everything manually?

Until now, the drop cap is set in the standard Linux Libertine. As visible in the following picture, it does not vertically align with the small caps at top nor the baseline of the third line. Is this done so by purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lines` option can't always compute precisely the font scale necessary for make the initial exactly fit; you can use the `loversize` option:

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[
  loversize=0.03,
  lines=3,
  slope=-0.5em,
  nindent=0pt,
  lhang=0.35
]{V}{ariablen}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what I get using Linux Libertine Initials:

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\lettrinefont{Linux Libertine Initials O}

\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\lettrinefont}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[
  loversize=0.03,lines=3,
  slope=-0.5em,
  nindent=0pt,
  lhang=0.35
]{V}{ariablen}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

The result left me speechless. What I can say is that I'd even prefer Comic Sans to this horrible thing. Since this possibility is out of the question, I have immediately removed the example file from my machine.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the design issue is not my part of work. Luckily. At least it works...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the `lraise` parameter? It would look like this.

```
\lettrine[lines=3, slope=-0.5em, nindent=0pt, lhang=0.35, lraise=0.1]{V}{ariablen}
```

Viel Spaß!

Comment: Thanks, I know that parameter. But first of all, I need to get the right font and do corrections afterwards. I will have to do some research, if my opinion about alignment is good style at all.

Comment: The ebgaramond package has a small selection of traditional ornate initials.